# PHP image upload with Laravel and AJAX returning empty image object

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

have everything set up for uploading images with Laravel except this issue.

I have made a class to handle all the image uploading, and then I have this ajax code:

```
$(document).on('submit', ".header-image-form", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:'/feature/uploadImage',
        data: new FormData(this),
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': $('form.header-image-form [name="_token"]').val()
        },
        async:false,
        type:'post',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
    });
});
```

This is my form:

```
<form class="header-image-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <input type="text" name="name" value="qwffwq">
    <input type="file" name="image" id="header-image-input">
</form>
```

And then my route:

```
Route::post('/feature/uploadImage', [
    'middleware' => 'isPublisher',
    'uses' => 'FeatureController@uploadImage'
]);
```

In my controller I am just returning back the request data and it returns the test field I put in the form but its returning an empty object for my image.

Where am I going wrong?